# AWS IAM Permissions for EC2 – Controlling Access on Specific Instances with particular region

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I am trying to set a group policy with IAM to provide access to the users at the particular region with specific vpc. As referring the AWS documents,trying to use vpc ID to filter the instances, since the resource-tag is not working with ec2 ( ResourceTag would be better option if its working with EC2). 
Created a following rule for the same, but it did not help,

```
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",  
"Statement": [    {
     "Action": [
             "ec2:RunInstances",
             "ec2:StartInstances",
             "ec2:Describe*" ],
     "Resource": "*",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Condition": {
     "StringEquals": {
     "ec2:Vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:*:vpc/vpc-123456"
       }
     }
    }    ] }
```

the result shows "An error occurred fetching Instance data" on EC2 page.

May I have any suggestions to fix this ?

Thank you

---

Thank you for you reply Rico :-)

Unfortunately,The given policy is did not work for me as per my requirement.

Need to give access to a user for particular region and user should have access to the instance which based on particular Resource tag or VPC or subnet or security group.

The user should not have privileges to launch or edit anything and user should able to list out the instances based on the filter as mentioned above to view the instance details (Read-only).

By considering above aspects, I have defined similar policy with dual condition ,since ARN is not working well with Resources for me.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
        [   
        "ec2:Region": "us-west-2",
        "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "Test"
       ]
     }
   }
  }  
 ]
}
```

When I use ARN for resource, it's not working for me on below format,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:1234567890:*/*",
        "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "Test"
     }
   }
 }  
 ]
}
```

I have tried with filtering Instances by using Resource tag, Instance ID, Security group and subnet.

Now I understand from your reply that VPC filter is not possible as of now.

Please refer the image for the Resource Tag of my instance.

[image]

Your prompt response will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

---

I have discussed with AWS Solution architect and the given following update,

The Describe* APIs for EC2 cannot be restricted to certain resources yet. 
In the initial releases of resource-level permissions for EC2 we focused on those actions  that create new or modify existing resources. 
See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources for the full list of actions in EC2 that support resource-level permissions.

We are working to extend the support for resource-level access control to more actions but we cannot provide with a date when this would be available for Describe* APIs.

Whether Resource-level permissions are supported or not depends on the action, see the link above. 
In particular, restricting EC2 Describe* Actions to resources is not possible as of now, but the above ARN can be used to restrict Actions that modify resources.

Resource Tag,subnet , security-group and vpc are supported in the "Condition" section of an IAM policy statement, but only for certain Actions – see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#amazon-ec2-keys for the available keys. However, Resource Tag,subnet , security-group and vpc are not supported in Conditions for the Describe* APIs.

---

Finally, I just ending with workaround by restricting a user with only region.

Answer (score 1):

So this is not possible using IAM at the moment, the only way is to use a `ResourceTag`. Curious as to why they are not working for you? I've have been interacting with AWS Support and this is their response:

> Unfortunately, there is not a way to do this at this time. While we do
>   now offer resource level permissions for EC2 resources, (more info
>   here...
>   http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/07/resource-permissions-for-ec2-and-rds-resources.html)
>   conditionally controlling access based on a specif VPC is not
>   supported.

This is because this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources shows that there are a limited number of EC2 API actions supported and none of them support VPC as a ARN.

There's also a limitation on "ec2:Describe*", which cannot be specified by a resource ARN at all, and cannot be conditionally controlled.

The workaround is to use the conditional statement "ResourceTag/tag-key" which is usable by most API calls. So you can potentially tag your instances with "Control":"Allow" and don't include the create or remove tag privileges in the policy to be attached to the user in question. Your policy would look like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:RebootInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Control": "Allow"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can restrict the user to launch instance just in a particular VPC using its `subnet-id`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:subnet/SUBNET-ID-HERE",
                "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:region::image/ami-*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To answer your question for a specific region, IAM policies are already region restricted, so this policy would only work on the specific region where you user that you are trying to restrict is on.

Hope this helps.